# AngularJS "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" for createHttpBackend

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS application works (well) for a user (Tomcat, using their personal Firefox).

When running a Selenium test (Jetty, Firefox), some exception occurs that I cannot explain:

```
Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: uuid in ngModel key: string:5
ngRepeatAction@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:15407
$watchCollectionAction@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8717
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8811
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:9012
done@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10265
completeRequest@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10449
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost:60690/webapp/frontend/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10407

return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

Now, the funny thing is: the duplicate string it is talking about (in this case "5", but I've seen other values as you'll understand from the following) seems to be some part of the GUID that I'm using as part of the call. So that GUID is in the URL and in the body of the request as well. (So when my GUID is c2d21d9c-9e14... it will fail on "2".)

I have some basic understanding of how duplicates are not desired in a repeater, but why are text string treated by a repeater in these pieces of Angular code? Of course there's duplicate characters used in text strings, right?!

By all means, I'd be really happy with a solution to the problem. But more generally: how would I approach a problem like this? It's asynchronous and not my code... Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS does not support duplicates in a ng-repeat directive. 
Try like bellow code snippet.

```
<div ng-repeat="r in [5,5,5] track by $index">
```

Comment: This looked more like Angular tokenizing some string *then* pulling it through `ngRepeat`. I surely must be able to have the same character more than once in a string ;) This is an old question, though, and I don't remember seeing this for a while now, might have gotten fixed by later Angular versions.